# Bad bind variable error while run the procedure

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

I'm getting PLS-00049 error when trying to execute procedure

I have doubt on cast and bind variable when using the collection type variables.

### I have the procedure named testprocedure and the input parameter is v_gcif is type array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type GCIF_ARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40);
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE test_procedure (
    V_IS_ARX_ENABLED IN VARCHAR2,
    V_GCIF           IN GCIF_ARRAY)
IS
  --V_GCIF    OD_CUSTOMER_MASTER_TBL.OD_GCIF%type;
  err_txt VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN  

  INSERT
  INTO test_table
    (
      OD_GCIF,
      OD_PROFILE_ID,
      OD_PROFILE_NAME
    )
  SELECT OD_GCIF,
    DEF_PROFILE_ID,
    PROFILE_NAME
  FROM test_map_table,
    test_temp_table

  WHERE DEF_PROFILE_ID = PROFILE_ID
  AND OD_GCIF         IN
    (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(CAST( :V_GCIF AS GCIF_ARRAY) )
    );

exception
  when others then
err_txt :='Error occured';

END;
```

--

when i run the procedure the below error during compilation

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'V_GCIF'
```

---

Pls can u explain what is going on and why that error occurs..

Comment: It's not a bind variable, but an IN variable of type GCIF_ARRAY for the Procedure. The usage doesn't allow ":" to reference it, as you would access a bind variable. You can access it the same way you access a normal variable. You also don't need this `CAST( :V_GCIF AS GCIF_ARRAY)`. Change it to `V_GCIF` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V_GCIF` is parameter passed to this procedure. So you don't need to add `:` before it in your procedure body.

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(CAST( :V_GCIF AS GCIF_ARRAY)
-- You don't need to specify :V_GCIF. Just use V_GCIF instead.
```

We use `:` to bind variables when we are executing sql statements via some code in programming language, for example, C#.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the colon in front of the V_GCIF variable.

Every reference to a PL/SQL variable is in fact a BIND VARIABLE.

Comment: can u explain pls y we dont need bind variables there

Comment: PL/SQL variables are implicitly bind variables when used in SQL statements.